# Why I cannot search in a folder twice by pressing a key on the keyboard? (Windows)

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

So there is this quick and easy search method when you open a folder you can press a key on the keyboard.

For example if you press the key 'e', a file or subfolder will be highlighted which name is starting with the letter 'e'.

If I keep pressing the 'e' key again and again, the highlight will iterate through all the subfolders and files which name is starts with 'e'.

It is fine and correct, but here comes the mindf:

When I would like to search for another starting letter like 'u' it does not starts the highlight thing, **it just popping the default "error" sound of windows.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because if you do this too fast, it will search for a folder/file with `eu`.

Comment: It is pretty unreliable, waiting for a second or pressing an (up or down) arrow key can help to reset the thing and let you press `u`.

Comment: @davidbaumann What is "eu" ?

Comment: e + u = eu......